# Pass HTML to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to pass html from a client(angularjs) app to server side (nodejs), i am trying to access the html via the req.body, but the object is always empty({}).

So on the client side, I just call the api passing the html:

```
generatePDF() {
    const htmlBlock = document.getElementById("templateArea");
    const htmlObj = {"element": htmlBlock};
    this.pdfService.generatePDF(htmlObj).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log("pdf generated");
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

the angular service does a post call.

everything fine, since it reaches the api, but then i try to access via console.log the req.body, that shows me always empty, any suggestion (i have the bodyparser already).

**my app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next();
});

app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**the route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pdfGenerator = require('../controllers/pdfGenerator');

router.post('/pdfURL', pdfGenerator.pdfToUrl );

module.exports = router;
```

**the controller**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
//var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };


module.exports = {
    pdfToUrl: function(req,res,next) {
        console.log(req.body);
        pdf.create('<div style="background-color:blue">a simple text</div>', options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
            console.log("asd"); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }    
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log("asd"); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
          });
    }
};
```

Comment: From what I know express doesn't know how to handle this type of data. Try to pass the html element as a string using innerHTML property and parse it on the server using cheerio or any other library.

Comment: Try sending the API a string instead of an HTML object. Is it still empty?